# Como declarar un ChoiceField en models.py

Tags: python, django

Buenas estoy modificando mi proyecto y decidi colocarle un ChoiceField pero cuando quiero realizar el `makemigrate` me arroja el siguiente error:

> File "/home/jbarreto/Documentos/Misproyectos/Personal/personal/datos/models.py", line 8, in Empleados
>       genero = models.ChoiceField()
>   AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'ChoiceField'

Este es mi **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models


class Empleados(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    ci = models.IntegerField()
    genero = models.ChoiceField()
    cargo = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    documento = models.FileField(
        upload_to="archivo/",
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s'% (self.nombre)
```

soy nuevo en esto necesito ayuda, gracias

Comment: puedes marcar tu respuesta como aceptada?

Answer (score 2):

En mi Models modifique:

```
   def __str__(self):
        return '%s'% (self.empleado)
```

En mi Forms:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin import widgets
from datos.models import Empleados, ActualizacionEmpleado
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, Select, EmailInput
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
widgets = {
            'nombre': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Introduzca nombre'}),
            'apellidos': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Introduzca apellidos'}),
            'genero': Select(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Seleccione su género'}),
            'ci': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'number','placeholder':'Introduzca ci'}),
            'cargo': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Introduzca cargo'}),
            'email': EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Introduzca email'}),
            'telefono': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Introduzca solo numero de telefono'}),
```

En mi Views:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView, DetailView
from .models import Empleados, ActualizacionEmpleado
from datos.forms import EmpleadoForm
```

En mi Urls:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from datos.views import EmpleadosView, EmpleadosUpdate, EmpleadosDelete, DetalleFormulario
```

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema, @Jhonny Barreto? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar los campos de STATUS un ejemplo seria primero definirlos:

```
 STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (1, "PENDIENTE"),
        (2, "En REVISION"),
        (3, "APROBADO"),
        (4, "RECHAZADO")
    )
```

luego de definirlo debes agregarlo a tu campo integer o char, en el ejemplo use un integer

```
genero = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES ,
            default=STATUS_CHOICES.PENDIENTE)
```

el modelo quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
 from django.db import models
 STATUS_CHOICES = (
            (1, "PENDIENTE"),
            (2, "En REVISION"),
            (3, "APROBADO"),
            (4, "RECHAZADO")
   )
        class Empleados(models.Model):

            nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
            apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=15)
            ci = models.IntegerField()
            genero = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES , default=STATUS_CHOICES.PENDIENTE)
            cargo = models.CharField(max_length=15)
            creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
            email = models.EmailField()
            telefono = models.CharField(max_length=12)
            documento = models.FileField(
            upload_to="archivo/",
            null=True,
            blank=True
            )

            def __str__(self):
                return '%s'% (self.nombre)
```

EDICION:
Para utilizarlo en la vista debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
empleado = Empleados(name="Fred Flintstone", genero=1)
empleado.save()
print (empleado.genero) # "sera 1"
empleado.get_genero_display() # "sera PENDIENTE
```

en tu vista

```
 {{ empleado.get_genero_display }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos formas de guardar posibles opciones que puede tener un campo y un modelo.

La primera es con `CharField`, y te ayudas del atributo `choices`, de la siguiente forma:

```
OPCIONES_GENERO = (
    ('M', 'MASCULINO'),
    ('F', 'FEMENINO'),
    ('O', 'OTRO')  # hay que ser inclusivos
)

genero = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=OPCIONES_GENERO)
```

De esta forma, en tus formularios, si dejas la configuración por defecto, para este modelo se hará un render del campo género con un select y las opciones serán las mismas que tienes en la variable `OPCIONES_GENERO`.

La otra forma es por medio de las relaciones ya sea `ForeignKey`, `OneToOneField` o `ManyToManyField`, las cuales también dejando la configuración por defecto de los formularios terminan renderizando un select, pero con las opciones que tengas en tu base de datos, de acuerdo a la relación